# Google Ads API not sending correct keyword estimates

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

As Google Ads provide keywords forecast service to see the estimated results. I am working on integrating the same in my clients site. I used Google Ads API and use the Estimate Keyword traffic API to get the results. All works fine but the result data is different if in Google Keyword Plan Tool and using the API? Anyone know why there is a difference?

Google Keyword planner shows:

### Keyword: chat robot, Clicks: 6.67, Cost: €3.31, CPC: €0.50

Results using API:

**Keyword: chat robot, Clicks: 0.97, Cost: €0.44, CPC: €0.46**